# setFilterModel doesnt perform filtering if filter is {type: 'equals' and filter: ''}

Tags: ag-grid

I am truing to use:

```
gridOptions.api.setFilterModel(filterModel);
```

with

```
var filterModel = { country: { type: 'equals', filter: '' } };
```

So i expect grid will return all rows with empty ''country'', but it looks like grid ignores passed filter with filter: ''

I also tried [null] as a values:

```
filterModel = { country: { type: 'equals', filter: [null] } };
```

in this case i see filter indicator near colunm header but rows is the same

maybe i missed something in documentation...

here is example
https://plnkr.co/edit/aA7D4At58yg7AqwD1qxc?p=preview

maybe someone can say how to perform filterig on blank values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right now its not posible with agGrid
hope they will add this soon
https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2712

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this github issue

https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2712

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, we replace empty values with a single space “ “ before populating the grid.
Then you can filter on using the usual `setFilterModel` to filter out rows with single space.

Hope this helps!